# How can I set breakpoints on all methods in class or in all class in package or by regex in JDB?

Tags: java, jdb

Official docs say how set individual breakpoint on source line or class method:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jdb.html

But I am interesting to make debug session in which I travel through all methods in selected package.

I use [BTrace](http://kenai.com/projects/btrace) to get trace of program. In BTrace I write regex pattern to match classes, methods and actions to be performed in runtime.

But unfortunately this instrument have limited capability to print argument of methods if they are out of primitive type.

By **jdb** I can dump any type but I does not know how to set 200 breakpoints automatically for all methods and classes in package.

Answer (score 1):

Use IDE debug tools. For example eclipse with http://java.decompiler.free.fr can help you.